# Foreach with different final loop

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to create a foreach loop which changes the values of two variables. The last iteration of the loop is slightly different (removed comma at the end) - I can't seem to get it to work.

This is what I have so far

```
$rego_columns = [
    "make", 
    "model", 
    "year",
    "rego",
];

    foreach ($rego_columns as $key => $regcolex) {
     if ($key === key($rego_columns)){
        $table_values = "'".$record["$regcolex"]."'";
        $table_columns = "`.$regcolex.`"; 
    } else {
        $table_values = "'".$record["$regcolex"]."',";
        $table_columns = "`.$regcolex.`,"; 
    }
}
```

Comment: consider using a `for` loop and use the index

Comment: what results are you getting now as opposed to the desired results? Define "not working".

Comment: $table_columns and $table_values are used in a mySQL insert query. Currently, there are no records being received by the insert

Comment: Those `\`.make.\``, etc strings don't look right. Also, PDO's prepared statement binding would surely help here

Comment: If this is a database related issue also as you stated in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53254753/foreach-with-different-final-loop#comment93394144_53254753) above, then the proper tags and code should be made part of the question, IMHO (<edit).

Comment: Seems like the plot thickens, as it were @Phil Wondering what the OP thought of your answer also. I voted this as being unclear and posted [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53254753/foreach-with-different-final-loop#comment93394216_53254753) just above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are effectively trying to map `$record` to your `$rego_columns`, I suggest using `array_map` to retrieve the values.

Then you can use `implode` to add the wrapping quotes or backticks around the array values.

### Example https://3v4l.org/h70pO

```
$rego_columns = [
    "make", 
    "model", 
    "year",
    "rego",
];

$record = ['make' => 'A', 'model' => 'B', 'year' => 'C', 'rego' => 'D'];

$tableValues = array_map(function($r) use ($record) {
    return $record[$r];
}, $rego_columns);

$tableColumns = '`' . implode('`,`', $rego_columns) . '`';
$tableValues = '"' . implode('","', $tableValues) . '"';


echo 'INSERT INTO table_name (' . $tableColumns . ') VALUES (' . $tableValues . ')';
```

Results in

```
INSERT INTO table_name (`make`,`model`,`year`,`rego`) VALUES ("A","B","C","D");
```

---

If you needed the dots included around the table column values for some reason, change the `implode` to:

```
$tableColumns = '`.' . implode('.`,`.', $rego_columns) . '.`';
$tableValues = '"' . implode('","', $tableValues) . '"';
```

Results in: https://3v4l.org/1DI76

```
INSERT INTO table_name  (`.make.`,`.model.`,`.year.`,`.rego.`) VALUES ("A","B","C","D")
```

---

As a side note, I strongly suggest using [`prepared statements`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) whenever using variable data with a database. And adopting this to map the values to the placeholders.

Example https://3v4l.org/kcl4m

```
$tableValues = array_map(function($r) use ($record) {
    return $record[$r];
}, $rego_columns);
$placeholders = implode(',', array_fill(0, count($tableValues), '?'));
$tableColumns = '`' . implode('`,`', $rego_columns) . '`';

$query = 'INSERT INTO table_name (' . $tableColumns  . ') VALUES(' . $placeholders . ')';    

$stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute($tableValues);
```